# Spyder external system terminal does not work (Python3.6)

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

I am not sure if this is a right place to ask this type of questions. I am a python beginner or programmer overall at this point. I am using Spyder to use python 3.6 (via Anaconda). I wrote a code that works fine when I run it in the current Ipython console. But I really need to run it in an external system terminal. In order to do so, I chose the following path: Run-> configuration per file -> execute in an external system terminal. That has been working fine. But now it refuses to work!

I validated that there is nothing wrong with my code by running something simple and saw that running via external system terminal does not work.

So far I deleted Anaconda and re-installed it. Could someone suggest what I should be looking for to diagnose the problem and fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Please run in a terminal (cmd.exe) `spyder --reset` and try again.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba, I typed spyder --reset. But it gives me an error message saying  "spyder" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. So I looked at the folders in my current directory. I have .anaconda, .conda, .condarc, .ipython, .matplotlib, .spyder-py3, anaconda3 . I'm not sure what's going wrong with it.. Thanks!

Comment: Please remove the .spyder-py3 folder and try again then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and noticed that unless the Working directory settings is set to "The directory of the file being executed", it won't work.

You can change it in "Run" > "Run configuration per file".